# Why changes from local state don't go into global state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

**To-Do-List**

When I try to edit my created task, I see some modifications, but only in local State. When I look at the data of the global state, nothing change, the data remains the same as after creating the tasks object.

It is also interesting to note that when case EDIT_TASK has worked , *action.id* = values from Input, and *action.task* = undefined

**P.S:** Put all the component code below, maybe there was a mistake somewhere.

**P.S:** Sorry for ENG

**Component's code**

```
import React from 'react'
import s from "./../../App.module.css";

class Item extends React.Component {
    state = {
        statusChange: false,
        task: this.props.task
    }

    activeStatusChange = () => {
        this.setState( {
            statusChange: true
           }
       );        
    }

    deActivateStatusChange = () => {
        this.setState( {
            statusChange: false
           }
       );
       this.props.editTask(this.props.task) 
    }

    onStatusChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            task: e.target.value
        }) 
    }


    render(){
        return (
            <div className={s.item}>
            <span onClick={this.props.editStatus} className={s.statusTask}>
                {this.props.status  ? <img src="https://img.icons8.com/doodle/48/000000/checkmark.png"/> 
                                    : <img src="https://img.icons8.com/emoji/48/000000/red-circle-emoji.png"/>}
            </span>

            { this.state.statusChange 
                ? <input  onChange={this.onStatusChange} autoFocus={true} onBlur={this.deActivateStatusChange} value={this.state.task} /> 
                : <span  className={this.props.status === true ? s.task : s.taskFalse} onClick={this.activeStatusChange}> {this.state.task} </span>}

            <span onClick={this.props.deleteTask} className={s.close}><img src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/close-window.png"/></span>

        </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Item;
```

**Reducer's code**

```
import React from 'react'
import shortid from 'shortid';

const ADD_TASK = 'ADD_TASK'
const EDIT_TASK = 'EDIT_TASK'

const initialState = {
    tasks: []
};



const mainReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {

        case ADD_TASK: {
            return {
                ...state,
                tasks: [{
                    id: shortid.generate(),
                    task: action.task,
                    status: false
                }, ...state.tasks]
            }
        }

        case EDIT_TASK: {
            return {
                ...state, 
                tasks: state.tasks.filter((t) => t.id === action.id ? {...t, task: action.newTask} : t)
            }
        }

    default:
        return state
    }
}

//window.store.getState().mainReducer.tasks

export const addTask = task => ({type: 'ADD_TASK', task});
export const editTask = (id,newTask) => ({type: 'EDIT_TASK', id, newTask})


export default mainReducer;
```

**Parent's component:**

```
import React from "react";
import s from "./../../App.module.css";
import CurrentTasks from "../current-tasks";
import FilterButtonTasks from "../filter-button-tasks";
import ListTasks from "../tasks-list";

class SetForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      text: ''
    }
  }

  onInputChange = event => {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    })
  }

  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    if(this.state.text === '') {
      return undefined
    } 
    this.props.addTask(this.state.text)
    this.setState({
      text: ''
    })
  }

  filterTasks = (tasks, activeFilter) => {

    switch (activeFilter) {
      case 'done': {
        return tasks.filter(task => task.status);
      }
      case 'active': {
        return tasks.filter(task => !task.status)
      }
      default:
        return tasks;
    }
  }


  render() {

    const currentTasks = this.filterTasks(this.props.tasks, this.props.filter);

    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <div>
            <input name={"text"} onChange={this.onInputChange} value={this.state.text}placeholder={"Set your task"} className={s.setTask}/>
            <button onClick={this.handleSubmit} className={s.add}>ADD</button>
            <button onClick={this.props.removeAllTasks} className={s.clearAll}>Clear</button>
          </div> 
        </form>
        <CurrentTasks tasks={this.props.tasks}/>
        <ListTasks   currentTasks={currentTasks} editStatus={this.props.editStatus} deleteTask={this.props.deleteTask} editTask={this.props.editTask}/>
        <FilterButtonTasks  currentTasks={currentTasks} changeFilter={this.props.changeFilter} removeAllDone={this.props.removeAllDone}/> 
      </div>
    )
  }
}



export default SetForm;
```

**one more:**

```
import React from 'react'
import Item from './SetItem/item'

const ListTasks = ({currentTasks,editStatus,deleteTask,editTask}) => {
    return (
        currentTasks.map(t => (<Item editStatus={() => editStatus(t.id)}
        deleteTask={() => deleteTask(t.id)}
        key={t.id} task={t.task} status={t.status} editTask={editTask}/>))
    )
}

export default ListTasks;
```

Comment: Seems like you are setting only local state inside function `onStatusChange ` and not calling `EDIT_TASK` action.

Comment: @Jagrati But editTask is an action... So how to make it rigth?

Comment: Somewhere you need to add `this.editTask(this.state.task)` , so that updated value gets written in global state

Comment: Can you add the code from parent component that is passing `editTask` prop to Item or create a sandbox for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, you are only updating the local state `onStatusChange` the state does not get updated in global state. So on `deActivateStatusChange` you need to call `this.props.editTask` with updated state, that is `this.state.task`

```
deActivateStatusChange = () => {
    this.setState({
      statusChange: false
    });
    this.props.editTask(this.state.task); // change is here
  };
```

The problem is in your `EDIT_TASK` reducer:

Change

```
state.tasks.filter((t) => t.id === action.id ? {...t, task: action.newTask} : t)
```

To

```
state.tasks.map((t) => t.id === action.id ? {...t, task: action.newTask} : t)
```

`map` will update the object, not `filter`

Code should be:

```
case EDIT_TASK: {
            return {
                ...state, 
                tasks: state.tasks.map((t) => t.id === action.id ? {...t, task: action.newTask} : t)
            }
        }
```

Also it seems like you are not passing id and newTask to editTask action:

```
const ListTasks = ({ currentTasks, editStatus, deleteTask, editTask }) => {
  return currentTasks.map(t => (
    <Item
      editStatus={() => editStatus(t.id)}
      deleteTask={() => deleteTask(t.id)}
      key={t.id}
      task={t.task}
      status={t.status}
      editTask={(newTask) => editTask(t.id, newTask)} // change current code to this
    />
  ));
```

};

Comment: I did it, but the same propblem :(

Comment: Check now. In `ListTasks ` use `editTask={(newTask) => editTask(t.id, newTask)}`